# How to start distributed Erlang app without starting dependencies at every node?

Tags: erlang, distributed, failover

I tried to run a simple app in a distributed manner to test failover-takeover features but failed.

***What I want to:***

The application is `myapp_api` with a rest api, it has `myapp` application as a dependency. I want to start `myapp_api` on 3 nodes, I want the whole app (`myapp_api` + `myapp`) to be working only at one node at the same time.

***What is wrong:***

The main app (`myapp_api`) works as expected: only at one node with failover and takeover. But for some reason depended `myapp` always starts at every node. I want it to be working only at one node at the same time.

***What I do:***

My config for the first node as an example.

```
[
    {kernel,
    [{distributed, [{myapp_api,
        1000,
        ['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]}]},
        {sync_nodes_optional, ['n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost']},
        {sync_nodes_timeout, 5000}
    ]}
].
```

I call
`erl -sname nI -config nI.config -pa apps/*/ebin deps/*/ebin -s myapp_api` at every node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now this gets a bit confusing because you say:

> I want to start myapp_api on 3 nodes, I want the whole app (myapp_api + myapp) to be working only at one node at the same time.

and you add:

> The main app (myapp_api) works as expected: only at one node with failover and takeover. But for some reason depended myapp always starts at every node.

In the first paragraph you say `myapp_api` should run everywhere, on the second quote you say it works as intended by booting on one node at a time.

I'll be assuming here that you want the whole set-up to be a failover, not just the top-level app and I just got confused on the first paragraph.

The config file you use shows what happens:

```
[{kernel,
  [{distributed, [{myapp_api,
    1000,
    ['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]}]},
    {sync_nodes_optional, ['n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost']},
    {sync_nodes_timeout, 5000}
]}].
```

The important bit is that `myapp_api` has the nodes `['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]` defined. This order means it runs on `n1@myhost` in top priority, and then on the other nodes with equal priority if there is a failover.

The thing is that none of the dependencies are distributed in the same way, and can therefore be expected to be running everywhere.

You should only need to expand on that config file to get it to work. Here I've done it and reindented it to show its structure better:

```
[{kernel,
  [{distributed, [
     {myapp_api, 1000, ['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]},
     {myapp, 1000, ['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]},
   ]},
   {sync_nodes_optional, ['n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost']},
   {sync_nodes_timeout, 5000}
]}].
```

I haven't tested it directly, but I'm pretty sure this will work.

If what you wanted was for `myapp_api` to be everywhere but for `myapp` to run in one place, you could use [global registration](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html), give a name to `myapp`'s public-facing process, get `myapp_api` to call these. `myapp_api` would then be able to route traffic to wherever `myapp` is when supported with the following config:

```
[{kernel,
  [{distributed, [
     {myapp, 1000, ['n1@myhost', {'n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost'}]},
   ]},
   {sync_nodes_optional, ['n2@myhost', 'n3@myhost']},
   {sync_nodes_timeout, 5000}
]}].
```

(See how `myapp` is the only app getting a distribution profile? Other apps will get to run on all nodes)

Comment: Yeah thanks, you got it right, i wanted the whole set-up to be a failover.  And yes, adding myapp to the distributed config worked as well. It's kinda strange for me that I had to do this manually.

Comment: It's only strange if you have simple setups. You could have non-homogenous clusters where apps A and C need to run on nodes 1,2,3,4 and then an app B that can only run on node 4 and 5 for hardware or OS reasons.

With different strategies for different apps, a more flexible approach like the one above makes sense.